# Django: using same test database in a separate thread

Tags: python, django, psycopg2, pytest

I am running pytests using a test database with the following DB settings.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'something',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',

    },
}
```

Using the @pytest.mark.django_db, my test functions access a database called 'test_postgres' created for the tests.

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_example():
    from django.db import connection
    cur_ = connection.cursor()
    print cur_.db.settings_dict
```

outputs:

```
{'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'NAME': 'test_postgres', 'TEST_MIRROR': None,...
```

but if I run a thread inside test_example:

```
def function_to_run():
    from django.db import connection
    cur_ = connection.cursor
    logger.error(cur_.db.settings_dict)

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_example():
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_to_run)
    p.start()
```

I can see that in that thread the cursor is using database named 'postgres' which is the non-testing database. Output:

```
{'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'NAME': 'postgres', 'TEST_MIRROR': None,...
```

Is there a way to pass a database connection argument to my thread from the original test function and tell my thread routine to use the same database name ('test_postgres') as my test function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround to my problem.

First you prepare a separate Django settings file for testing (settings_pytest.py), with the following DATABASES setting:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'test_database',
        'TEST_NAME': 'test_database',
        'USER': 'something',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',

    },
}
```

Notice that we define TEST_NAME, and it's the same as NAME, so that running through test runner or not, we will be accessing same database.

Now you need to create this database, and run 'syncdb' and 'migrate' on it first:

```
sql> CREATE DATABASE test_database;

manage.py syncdb --settings=settings_pytest

manage.py migrate --settings=settings_pytest
```

Finally you can run your tests with:

```
py.test --reuse-db
```

You need to specify --reuse-db, database re-creation will never work since the default database is the same as the test database. If there are changes to your database you will need to recreate the database manually with the commands above.

For the test itself, if you are adding records to the database that you need to be accessed by the spawned child process, remember to add transaction=True to the pytest decorator.

```
def function_to_run():

    Model.objects.count() == 1

@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def test_example():
    obj_ = Model()
    obj_.save()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_to_run)
    p.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `function_to_run()` declaration you're doing `from django.db import connection`. Are you sure that will be using the correct test db settings? I suspect the decorator you're using modifies the `connection` import to use the `test_postgres` rather than `postgres` but because you're importing outside of the decorators scope it's not using the right one. What happens if you put it inside the decorator-wrapped function like so...

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_example():

    def function_to_run():
        from django.db import connection
        cur_ = connection.cursor
        logger.error(cur_.db.settings_dict)

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_to_run)
    p.start()
```

Edit:

I'm not familiar with pytest_django so I'm shooting in the dark at this point, I imagine that the marker function allows you to decorate a class as well, so have you tried putting all the tests that want to use this shared function and the db in one TestCase class? Like so:

```
from django.test import TestCase

@pytest.mark.django_db
class ThreadDBTests(TestCase):

    # The function we want to share among tests
    def function_to_run():
        from django.db import connection
        cur_ = connection.cursor
        logger.error(cur_.db.settings_dict)

    # One of our tests taht needs the db
    def test_example1():
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_to_run)
        p.start()

    # Another test that needs the DB
    def test_example2():
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_to_run)
        p.start()
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, the above gives a 'PicklingError: Can't pickle <function function_to_run at 0x0000000006901208>: it's not found as ...'. Also, I would like to share the thread function among many tests. I tried decorating the thread function with the pytest.mark.db, however it won't do anything since it is run through multiprocessing module and not the test runner.

Comment: I tried making it a class method, but still the database used is the default one, not the test database. I think the problem is that we are not running child process through any of django test runners - which I don't want to since it's not a test (there is no PASS/FAIL). I would like to be able to control the django settings of that child process, but I haven't been able to.