# How to test other thread that access database

Tags: python, django, multithreading, unit-testing

It seem that the database used by django during tests isn't shared with other thread

For example:

inside a TestCase class :

```
def my_test(self):
    print(MyModel.objects.all())
    my_function()
```

inside my class :

```
def worker():
    print(MyModel.objects.all())

def my_function():
    thread = Thread(target=worker)
    thread.start()
```

Console result :

```
[<MyModel object>, <MyModel object>, <MyModel object> ... ]
[]
```

So We get the first call, but as soon as we are inside another thread, it doesn't use the test db anymore.

I looked at : [Django: using same test database in a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22960735/django-using-same-test-database-in-a-separate-thread) 
and tried to use the same db for "NAME" and "TEST_NAME" but it doesn't work for me

What could I do to test my threads even if they are accessing db ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django's `TestCase` runs each test class in a single transaction. Any changes are not committed, so other threads cannot read the effects of those changes.

The solution is to use a `TransactionTestCase`. It will run queries in the default autocommit mode, and your changes will immediately be available to other threads.